# How to get a subset of comparing two vectors of pairs?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

How to get a third vector which is to be a subset of comparing two vectors of pairs if two or more of the pairs int's (first) are a subset of each vector.

```
const std::vector<std::pair<int, MyObj>> lhs; 
const std::vector<std::pair<int, MyObj>> rhs;
```

The result by comparing vectorA and vectorB:

```
vectorA
    pair(1, obj1)
    pair(2, obj2)
    pair(3, obj3)
    pair(4, obj4)

vectorB
    pair(2, obj2)
    pair(4, obj4)
    pair(5, obj5)
    pair(6, obj6)
```

Should result in vectorC containing:

```
pair(2, obj2)
pair(4, obj4)
```

I've been looking at `std::set_intersection`, but couldn't see how to do this with pairs.

Comment: If I understand correctly, did you try `set_intersection` with a custom compare like `[](auto a, auto b){ return a.first < b.first; }`?

Comment: No, not like that. Let me give that a try.

Comment: I used `set_intersection`, and it worked on my machine.  Maybe the problem is in how you had tried to use it?  I did not make a custom compare.

Comment: `set_intersection` requires sorted vectors. Since yours are const that may complicate things if they are not already sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if you want to find the intersection of 2 [`std::vector`s](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), the you can use the [`std::set_intersection`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/) algorithm. If the vecotrs are not provided in sorted order, then they have to be sorted by [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

In both algorithms the elements are compared using the `operator<`. If `operator<` is not defined on the element type of the vector, then you have to explicitly pass a comparator to the `std::sort` respectively `std::set_intersection` algorithm:

```
#include <vector>       // std::vector, std::set_intersection
#include <utility>      // std::pair
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
#include <iterator>     // std::back_inserter
```

```
bool comp(
    const std::pair<int, MyObj> &a,
    const std::pair<int, MyObj> &b )
{
    return a.first < b.first; 
}
```

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, MyObj>> lhs; 
std::vector<std::pair<int, MyObj>> rhs; 

std::sort( lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), comp );
std::sort( rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), comp );

std::vector<std::pair<int, MyObj>> result;
std::set_intersection(
    lhs.begin(), lhs.end(),
    rhs.begin(), rhs.end(),
    std::back_inserter(result), comp );
```

Comment: When I tried to repro Ender's problem, I had declared the lhs and rhs vectors in already sorted order.  But the requirement that they are already sorted is important.

Comment: (Probably don't want result to be const.)